# Pasar datos de JField Text a un JCombo Box con un boton

Tags: java

Buenas estaba realizando un pequeño ejercicio: 
Queria que al presionar el Boton se guardara la info en el combo box, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, he tratado de diferentes formas para guardar dentro de un arreglo para almacenar la info y que luego se mostrara en el combo box.

```
String[] v_arreglo = new String[5];
  JLabel v_label2 = new JLabel();
        v_label2.setText("Digite los datos: ");
        v_label2.setVisible(true);
        v_label2.setLocation(20, 50); //cuando no se muestra
        v_label2.setSize(200, 20);
        v_frame.add(v_label2);

        JTextField v_nombre2 = new JTextField();
        v_nombre2.setBounds(200, 50, 200, 20);
        v_nombre2.setVisible(true);
        v_frame.add(v_nombre2);
        v_frame.setVisible(true);

        JComboBox v_combo1 = new JComboBox(v_arreglo);
        v_combo1.setBounds(190, 200, 120, 50);
        v_combo1.setVisible(true);
        v_combo1.setEnabled(true);
        v_frame.add(v_combo1);

        JButton v_boton2 = new JButton();
        v_boton2.setText("Almacenar");
        v_boton2.setBounds(150, 70, 100, 70);
        v_boton2.setVisible(true);
        v_frame.add(v_boton2);

        v_boton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for (int i = 0; i < v_arreglo.length; i++) {
                    v_arreglo[0] = v_nombre.getText();
                    v_combo.addItem(v_arreglo[i]);

                }

            }
        });


        v_frame.repaint();
        v_frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Agradezco la asistencia.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta repintando el comboBox

```
v_boton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            for (int i = 0; i < v_arreglo.length; i++) {
                v_arreglo[0] = v_nombre.getText();
                v_combo.addItem(v_arreglo[i]);
                v_combo.repaint();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Lo voy a intentar, pero sigue sin mostrarme los datos en el combo box

Comment: No entendí, ya lo pusiste o todavía no?

Comment: Lo puse pero no cargo el combo box

Comment: Buenas si le  cambie el codigo pero no he logrado cargar los datos en el arreglo, y perdon por la tardanza en la respuesta dado que tuve problemas con la cuenta